# How to highlight cell based on certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet 1 with the following data (thousands of it):

```
   column A         colum B    
1  Tag_Number       WBS      
2  61LV    -1502    6103    
3  61LV    -1508    6104    
4  61PDT   -1013    6002    
5  61PDT   -2943    6191
```

I also have sheet 2 with the same information but data might not be in the same exact order:

```
   column A         colum B
1  Tag_Number       WBS  
2  61LV    -1508    6104
3  61LV    -1502    6103
4  61PDT   -1013    6002
5  61PDT   -2943    6191
```

How can I make B3 in sheet 2 to highlight yellow because the data for sheet 2 61LV    -1502 6103  is not the same as 61LV  -1502 WBS 6103?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim val, cell As Range, rows1 As Long, rows2 As Long
    rows1 = Sheet1.Range("A32767").End(xlUp).Row
    rows2 = Sheet2.Range("A32767").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet2.Activate
    For Each cell In Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & rows2).Cells
        val = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(cell, Sheet1.Range("A2:B" & rows1), 2, False), "")
        If val = "" Then
            MsgBox "Tag not found: " & cell.Value
            cell.Select
            Exit For
        ElseIf cell.Offset(, 1).Value <> val Then
            cell.Offset(, 1).Select ' or change interior color
            Exit For ' or dont exit if you want to color all unmatched cells
       End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```